# angular infinite digest loop from ng-model using getterSetter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the html:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" ng-model="vm.orgType" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" ng-options="orgType as orgType.ORGANIZATION_TYPE for orgType in vm.orgTypes">
                                </select>
```

and here is the getter/setter function:

```
function orgType(selectedType) {
            if (arguments.length == 0)
                return orgType.selectedOrgType || { ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null };

            orgType.selectedOrgType = selectedType;
            if (selectedType.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID) {
                if (vm.registrant.StakeholderOrgs[0])
                    vm.registrant.StakeholderOrgs[0] = selectedType.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID;
                else
                    vm.registrant.StakeholderOrgs.push(selectedType.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID);
            }
            else
                vm.registrant.StakeholderOrgs.splice(0);
        }
```

the following line:

```
return orgType.selectedOrgType || { ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null };
```

throws the infinite digest loop error.

Let me explain what I am trying to do here. I need to push the id onto a list if there is a selection made. I realize that I could just do an ng-model on some variable `selectedOrgType` and then just put my logic in an ng-change. However, I am trying to make a dropdown that does not create any unnecessary model variables. Instead, I was hoping to just put the logic in a getter/setter, that seems more appropriate to me. One of `vm.orgTypes` is `{ ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null }`, I was hoping that would be my default value instead I get this digest error, don't understand where it is coming from.

Comment: watch in this case check equals by reference, and if you return `{ ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null }` you every check return _new_ object. If you have same object in collection - just use it like `return orgType.selectedOrgType || vm.orgTypes[0]`. Or just save in variable: `var defVal = { ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null }` and use `return orgType.selectedOrgType || defVal`

Comment: @Grundy Want to add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add `ng-model` attribute, angular add internal watch, that check value on every digest loop, and if value changed - run digest again.

In you case you return object literal. In javascript when you compare two literals, even with same structure - you get *false*

```
({a:1} == {a:1}) // false
```

because this really two different object.

So, when you return object literal in your getter, `watch` check it with previous value, and, as i say above, if you return literal - get *false*

So you get your error with infinite digest.

For solving you just need return same object.

If you have this object inside array, like

```
vm.orgTypes=[
    { ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null }
];
```

So you just need use it directly:

```
 return orgType.selectedOrgType || orgTypes[0];
```

Yer another way: just save default falue to varible and use it

```
var defaultSelect = { ORGANIZATION_TYPE: 'Organization Type', ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID: null };

....

function orgType(selectedType) {
    if (arguments.length == 0)
        return orgType.selectedOrgType || defaultSelect;
```

In this case you would return same element in default case, so avoid infinite digest loot.

Comment: I'm trying to normalize an input. The `input` can be `input[type=text]` or it can be a `<select>`. I'm always returning an object litereal -- I need to. How would you get around this? Your Answer wasn't *really* a solution -- you just said *don't do that*.

Comment: @Cody, possibly you not see code after _For solving you just need return same object._ Anyway, you can ask your own question, because problem can be somewhere else

Comment: I saw the *return same object* line -- which works like a charm, **if** you can return the same object. I my case, it may not even be an option. Thx for the input though.

Comment: @Cody, without your code, i can't suggest how apply my answer to your issue :)