# md- datePicker - Date instance error always

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I am getting this error `The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: string`. I am using moment..

in view

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="Model.currentContact.getSetIncorporated" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

in model

```
Contact.prototype.getSetIncorporated = function(date) {
        if (arguments.length) {
            this.company.information.incorporatedObject = date;
            this.company.information.incorporated = moment.utc(date).format('X');
        }
        if (!this.company.information.incorporatedObject) {
            if (this.company.information.incorporated !== '') {
                this.company.information.incorporatedObject = moment.utc(this.company.information.incorporated, 'X').toDate();
            } else {
                this.company.information.incorporatedObject = null;
            }}
        return this.company.information.incorporatedObject;
    }
```

Also I have tried several mdLocale.formatDate and parseDate. Current version is

```
$mdDateLocale.formatDate = function(date) {

            return moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        };

        $mdDateLocale.parseDate = function(dateString) {

            var m = moment(dateString, 'YYYY/MM/DD', true);
            return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
        };
```

the server is sending this string `2016-09-10T22:00:00.000Z`

When I convert that string to Date object with new Date(), I get right result showing in mdDatePicker but I get also 
`Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`
which brakes my page.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. The value you are passing to `Model.currentContact.getSetIncorporated` is a string rather than a date.

Here is an example of the problem - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/PGkJxG?editors=1010#0). The console shows the error.

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.myDate = new Date();
  this.myDate = this.myDate.toString(); // Comment this out to work correctly
});
```

This question - [How to check whether an object is a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643782/how-to-check-whether-an-object-is-a-date) - will explain how to check whether you are passing a string or a date.

**Update:**

The reason for the message

> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.

seems to be because `Contact.prototype.getSetIncorporated` is returning a Date. Returning a string works but the `ng-model` requires a Date!

Here's a way to get round that problem - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/xEVkXq?editors=1010#0).

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.myDate = new Date();

  this.test = function () {
    return new Date();
  }  
  this.testModel = this.test();
});
```

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.testModel"  ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" ng-change="change()"></md-datepicker>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it is a string... I even try converting that string with new Date(stringDate), but got infinite digest loop error.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: @Alexa - You may want to add that your question as that may be the main problem.

Comment: What to do then? It must be a function, that is the code given to me...


Maybe converting to Date object must be done in mdDateLocale, but it is not working, I tried many combinations.

Comment: I found something, but don't know how to get it work..It must return same instance of an date object.. So how to dinamicaly change Date object valueOf? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287911/angular-infinite-digest-loop-from-ng-model-using-gettersetter

Comment: I see it is working on Codepen, but don't know why... I don't know how to get this to work with code pattern I got using functions in model... I have a lot of functions like this... Maybe to try to do something generic for all in mdDateLocale.. because I must format them all with timeZones. Also in my model functions I get paramether as date which is undefined in codepen.

Comment: @Alexa I hope I helped you towards a solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

when you use moment you have to take the _d property from moment:

```
    var _convertStringToDate = function (stringDate) {

        var date;
        if (angular.isString(stringDate)) {
            date = moment(stringDate)._d;
        }

        return date;
    };
```

Comment: I got 
`Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`